# Equivalent of date --reference in Solaris

Tags: shell, solaris, date, stat

The GNU implementation of the `date` command has a nice feature to show the date of the last modification of a reference file. Then using the `+FORMAT` parameter it's easy to get the date in any format, for example:

```
date -r /etc/motd +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S
# output in the format: 20121001_171233
```

Is there an equivalent for this in Solaris? 
As a workaround, I do it using the `stat` function of `perl` like this:

```
perl -mPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S\n", localtime((stat("/etc/motd"))[9]))'
```

Another alternative is to parse the output of `ls -Ego`:

```
ls -Ego /etc/motd | awk '{print $4 "_" $5}' | tr -d :- | sed -e 's/\..*//'
```

But parsing the output of `ls` is known to be a bad practice.

Is there a better/simpler/more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inability of `date` to print anything but the current date is an oft-lamented defect. Some unices allow it to print other dates, but sadly for you not Solaris.

As long as you only need numerical output, you can parse the output of `ls -Ego`. The options `-go` suppres the user and group name, and `-E` is a Solaris-specific option to [`ls`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/ls-1.html#scrolltoc) that makes it display the time in a parseable format.

```
ls -Ego /path/to/file |
awk 'NR==1 {$0 = $4 "_" $5; gsub(/[-:]/,""); sub(/\..*/, ""); print}'
```

(This works with `/usr/bin/ls` but requires a POSIX-compliant awk, so make sure to have `/usr/xpg4/bin` or `/usr/xpg6/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`, or call `nawk`.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that Perl is your best bet; I don't know of any useful date converter in Solaris, and `date` command only prints or sets current time.

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly the format you want but how about

```
stat -c %y /etc/motd
=>
  2011-03-08 11:39:20.000000000 +0000
```

and then use whatever you prefer to bring that timestamp into shape.

**Edit**
I'm assuming OpenSolaris or Solaris 11 where the GNU version of `stat` is bundled.

Comment: Is there a stat command in Solaris? Not that I know of. (* with exception of the ksh shell, where there is a shell builtin, I'm told)

Comment: There is a `stat` command in Solaris 11, but then if you have Solaris 11, there is also the simpler solution of just using `/usr/gnu/bin/date`.

Comment: I'm in Solaris 10. I found GNU date in `/usr/local/bin/date`. That's a good workaround, but it would be good to know another solution in case GNU date is not available.